# can't connect ubuntu server to internet

Tags: networking, server, internet

I am new to ubuntu server and i can't manage to connect it to the internet. It is the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Even during the internet setup window for the installation the wifiscan couldn't start. I got a error message something with -100

First I tried to follow the instructions  [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/connect-to-wifi-network-on-ubuntu-server/) to connect the system to the network, but it didn't work. Afterwards I tried these stuffs.

run lshw:

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network DISABLED
description: Wireless Interface
product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
```

... too much text to type out

when i ran ifconfig:

```
ifconfig
command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install net-tools
```

after running rfkill:

```
rfkill list all
Command 'rfkill' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install rfkill

sudo apt install rfkill
E: Failed to fetch http://.......deb Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How can I connect it to the internet, so i can use for example ssh?

**EDIT1:**

Yesterday, I attempted to install Ubuntu Server once again. This time, I connected my laptop to the internet using an Ethernet cable. During the installation setup, it prompted that there was a new installation version and asked if I wanted to update it. It successfully updated and even checked the mirrors without any problems. However, when I tried to set up the Wi-Fi alongside the Ethernet in the installation set up phase, it didn't work. After completing the entire installation process, the computer had no internet connection again. Neither the Ethernet nor the Wi-Fi connections worked.

**EDIT2:**

I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 now on a windows computer and prepared there the bootable stick. After the installation of Ubuntu, somehow my laptop manages to connect to the internet via ethernet. I still can't connect it via wifi. I tried `ip a` and `nmcli dev status` and got. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OsI5.jpg)

Comment: Server? WiFi? Please explain. Also, there is never *"too much text to type out"*, if you actually want any help.

Comment: @ArturMeinild is there a way to copy the text from the server and paste it to another computer?

Comment: Similar-looking bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1993890

Comment: @pira1999, welcome to AskUbuntu! Thank you for trusting us with your question. I've run into some issues setting up wifi on Ubuntu Server as well, but it was several, several years ago. So, for starters, check out <a href="https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/configure-wifi-connections">this</a> guide and see if the steps help you out any. Please let us know if this answers your question!

Comment: @Geary sadly I didn't find any answers, but i though about using keryx tool to download the nettool package on a usb drive and then install on ubuntu